# Smallest vector that solves a specific linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am looking for the smallest vector $z$ (w.r.t. the Euclidean norm) that solves the linear system,
\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1\\2&3&5&7\\-2&-1&1&3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v\\u\\x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\7\\-1\end{pmatrix}  \end{equation}

I've determined that $x$ should be of the form,
\begin{equation} z = \begin{pmatrix} -1 + 2x  + 4y\\ 3 - 3x - 5y \\ x \\y\end{pmatrix} \end{equation}

So I am looking to minimize the function,
$$f(x,y) = || z ||^2 = x^2 + y^2 + (-1 + 2x  + 4y)^2 + (3 - 3x - 5y )^2.$$

After taking partial derivatives to find the critical points, I believe I am left with the system,
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 14 & 23\\ 23 & 42 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ 19 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

If the above is 100% correct, I'd have to be a little surprised simply because this is a question from a paper and pencil test, and the final system is not "pretty" because it takes a decent amount of arithmetic to compute $x$ and $y.$

My question(s):

1) Does anyone know of a faster way to compute the smallest vector? Is there a more elegant way rather than using 2 systems?

2 - less important) Is the work above correct?

Comment: 2) Yes it is correct.

Comment: I don't know if it will necessarily end up being easier, but you can try LaGrange multipliers, trying to minimize $x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2$ constrained by the given equations.